# Закрытие браузера на мобильном устройстве

Tags: php, javascript, telegram-bot

У меня в телеграм-боте, есть функционал по которому пользователю возвращается ссылка. Ссылка ведет на мой ресурс, где выполняются кое-какие действия, после чего, выводится сообщение(успешное/не успешное) + кнопка вернутся в телеграм.

Как мне при ее нажатие, закрыть браузер на телефоне-планшете?

Comment: window.close(), но не факт. Скорее всего, закроется вкладка.

Comment: А чем аппаратная кнопка back не угодила?

Comment: window.close() не закрывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо сделать **редирект** пользователя на своего бота по ссылке, вида `https://telegram.me/<YourBot>`. Браузер закроется (*или свернётся, в зависимости от платформы клиента*).